# Using Steam Inventory in rpg maker mv

Tags: steam-web-api, steamworks-api, rpgmakermv

I am currently working on a project in rpg maker mv and i have run into a slight problem.

I am using hudells steamworks api to get player data for my game and i have discovered it does not cover the steam inventory, so i want to use the players steam id to get the players steam inventory of that specific game and add or remove items to the players inventory based on the steam inventory using the web api.

Is that at all possible and if it is how do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Steam Web API documentation can be found [here](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/).

You are most likely interested in the [IInventoryService -> Get Inventory](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/IInventoryService#GetInventory) endpoint. However, use of this endpoint requires a publisher API key, which requires registration and payment on Steamworks. The [user API key](https://steamcommunity.com/dev/apikey) will not work for this endpoint.

So the answer to your question is probably not, unless you are willing to go through the effort of registering through Steamworks.

Comment: If you have a publisher API key, then you can use the endpoint mentioned in my answer. (https://partner.steam-api.com/IInventoryService/GetInventory/v1/)